# Get past tweets

Tags: rest, twitter, data-mining

Good morning, 
for an academic project I need to perform some data analysis on tweets. 
I would need a huge number of past tweets. 
Using the classical twitter API search, I have some limits on the days I can go back fetching tweets, how can I get all tweets I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can contact a company that sells this data.

Because I do not want to advertise for any of them, I will not include links here.

The Twitter TOS do not allow sharing tweets (so you will not find a legal download location), and their API only offers the last few days, so you will need commercial providers that have an agreement with Twitter.